# how to get likes_count of a public instagram post using graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I tried using ["meta for developers"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-profiles-and-media/) to link my instagram business account and use the instagram graph API to get the likes account of a media id.

It works fine as long the post belongs to my account. If I try to access details of any other instagram account or post, I'm getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "AZWB7w2MymKczqxevPpnxEf"
  }
}
```

Is it allowed to get media and other information of a public instagram page using graph APIs?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the document here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery#endpoints

As stated by Instagram [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api):

*The API is intended for Instagram Businesses and Creators who need insight into, and full control over, all of their social media interactions. If you are building an app for consumers or you only need to get an app user's basic profile information, photos, and videos, consider the Instagram Basic Display API instead.*

Comment: I'm able to get information about my social media post using the media id. But my issue is using media id of different public accounts give me authentication failure error. I want to get likes/comment count of different public instagram account.
Using business discovery API, I can only access the profile of business/creator. But I want to track their particular post (by giving url and converting it media id somehow)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you can use business discovery API to retrieve any post's data, including like, comment, share, URL.